# asp.net dynamic HTML form

Tags: asp.net, html, response

I want to create an html page inside a asp.net page using c# and then request that html page. The flow is, I'll be creating a request that will give me a response with some values. Those values will be stored in hidden fields in the html page I'm creating on the fly and then requesting. I figure it would be something like below but I'm not sure if it would work, I've also received some "Thread Aborting" errors. So, does anyone know the proper way to do this or at least direct me to a nice article or something?

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("<html><head></head>");
builder.Append("<body onload=\"document.aButton.submit();\">");
builder.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"something\" value=\"" + aValue + "\">");
HttpContext.Current...Response.Write(builder.ToString());
... end response
```

Comment: This is a very common request and is almost never a good idea. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common request and is almost never a good idea. What are you trying to do?

That said: you write out a file with a temporary name and redirect to that file. Later you have to figure out when it's safe to delete the file.

**Edit** That method points out one of the problems: you have to do your own garbage collection, deciding how long files must be kept around and deleting them appropriately.

Comment: I answered your question, now you answer mine :)